# Flutter : Provider do not update data in the previous screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

In my Flutter application I am using `Provider` version 4.0.4 to manage the state of my app. In basic terms, my app will list down the nearby companies with their rating. users can select a organisation, open it and add their rating as well, so the final rating will be updated. I am using the `Consumer` concept in `Provider` to handle the tasks.

1. In `NearByPlacesPage` class I am listing down the companies around me with rating information. User can click on a company and they will be taken to `OrganizationPage` page.
2. In `OrganizationPage` class, the rating is displayed again.  user can add their rating to the system. Then the rating information in both `OrganizationPage` page and `NearByPlacesPage` (back page) need to be updated.

The issue is, when the user update the rating, the rating in `OrganizationPage` get updated but not `NearByPlacesPage` in back stack. When we go back to `NearByPlacesPage`, we can clearly see the old rating values. The page need to be reloaded to get updated values.

Below are the important sections in my code

**NearByPlacesPage**

```
    class NearByPlacesPage extends StatelessWidget {
      int orgTypeID;
      String orgTypeName;
    
      NearByPlacesPage(this.orgTypeID, this.orgTypeName);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => RatingService()),
            ],
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: _NearByPlacesPageUI(orgTypeID, orgTypeName),
            ),
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(orgTypeName),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

class _NearByPlacesPageUI extends StatefulWidget {
  int orgTypeID;
  String orgTypename;

  _NearByPlacesPageUI(this.orgTypeID, this.orgTypename);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NearByPlacesPageState();
  }
}

class _NearByPlacesPageState extends State<_NearByPlacesPageUI> {
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Consumer<RatingService>(builder: (context, data, child){
    return Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: orgList.length,
            itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index) {
                Organization organization = orgList[index];

                if (organization.isDisabled != true) {
                   RatingValue ratingValue = data.getData();

                    return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 5, left: 5, right: 5),
                            child: _buildPlace(organization, ratingValue));
                } else {
                    return Container();
                 }
            },),
        );
    },);
  }
}
```

**OrganizationPage**

```
class OrganizationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Organization organization;
  String orgTypeName;

  OrganizationPage(this.organization, this.orgTypeName);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: _OrganizationPageUI(organization, orgTypeName),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(organization.name),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _OrganizationPageUI extends StatefulWidget {
  Organization organization;
  String orgTypeName;

  _OrganizationPageUI(this.organization, this.orgTypeName);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _OrganizationPageState();
  }
}

class _OrganizationPageState extends State<_OrganizationPageUI> {

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Consumer<RatingService>(
       builder: (context, data, child) {

        Consumer<RatingService>(

            return Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                        child: Text(daa.getData()
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.apply(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            );
                        
        ),
            
        }
    }
}
```

In **OrganizationPage** there is a `AlerDialog`, which allows the user to rate and save. When saved, it will call another method which will reload the data.

```
Widget _ratingDialog(double _rating) {
    RatingService _ratingService =
        Provider.of<RatingService>(context, listen: false);
    Rating _rating = _ratingService.returnRating();
    double _ratingValue = _ratingService.returnRating().rating;

    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text("Your Rating"),
      actions: [
        new FlatButton(
          child: const Text("Save"),
          //onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          onPressed: () async {
            Rating rating = Rating(
                    idrating:
                        _rating.idrating != null ? _rating.idrating : null,
                    user: _user,
                    organization: widget.organization,
                    rating: _ratingValue,
                    dateCreated: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                    lastUpdated: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);

                await _ratingService.saveOrUpdateRating(rating, authToken);
                _loadRatingByUserAndOrganization(authToken);
                _loadRatingValueByOrganization(authToken);

                Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future _loadRatingByUserAndOrganization(String authToken) {
    RatingService _ratingService =Provider.of<RatingService>(context, listen: false);

    return _ratingService.getRatingByUserAndOrganization(
        _authService.getDatabaseUser().user.iduser,
        widget.organization.idorganization,
        authToken);
    
  }
```

**RatingService**

This is the class which is responsible for calling `notifyListeners()`. It will be triggered by the above `AlertDialog` and the expected behaviour is to reload data in both `OrganizationPage` and `NearByPlacesPage`

```
class RatingService with ChangeNotifier {

  List<RatingValue> _ratingValueList ;

  List<RatingValue> getData()
  {
    return _ratingValueList;
  }

  //Load rating by user and Organization
  Future<void> getRatingByUserAndOrganization(int idUser, int organizationID, String authToken) async {
 
    try {
      var data = await http.get(
        _navLinks.getRatingByUserAndOrganization(idUser, organizationID),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $authToken"},
      );
      print(data.body);
      _rating = Rating.fromJson(convert.json.decode(data.body));
   

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

What I have I done wrong?

Comment: Could you make it simpler? Just a simple example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: in NearByPlacesPage you're creating a RatingService in the MultiProvider, but OrganizationPage is consuming a RatingService, how is that possible if they're in different routes and they cannot see each other RatingService, are you creating another Ratingservice somewhere else?

Comment: Please add all the code of `RatingService` class. For Example `_ratingService.returnRating()` how did you call this there is no method in your given code. Please provide more info.